# Website Developer has gone missing! How to gain full access of your code from a Wordpress website?

Tags: theme-development, database, code, file-manager

I have hired a website developer to create a Wordpress website for me.

The website is nearly finished, but the website developer has gone missing!

I have admin access to the Wordpress dashboard.

How can I download the code to my website so that I have a backup, in case the website developer tries to do anything.

They have created a tailored theme under their own name. I have been doing some research and apparently I need the database they created as well? If so, how can I get a backup of this?

In a tricky situation where they seem to have most of the control when I have paid them to help me build a website!

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to the hosting account?

Comment: Hi Jacob, I should have mentioned, they have access to the hosting account, as they created this. Do you know what I should do if they have access?

Comment: If you don’t have access yourself there is basically nothing you can do. At least from a technical perspective. If you know who the host is at least it might be worth reaching out to them to see what they can do.

Comment: I am not sure who the host is, this is my predicament. I have researched that I can download the database from the Wordpress admin with a plug-in?

Comment: @JacobPeattie What about using UpdraftPlus plug-in?

Comment: Sorry I missed that you had admin access. I assumed that you didn’t as this is much less of a problem if you do. Yes there are plugins you can use to download this sort of thing, but I’ve never used them so I can’t be if much help there.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have admin access, the first thing to do is to downgrade his admin user to 'contributor' (lowest level). If you have been sharing the admin access, create a new admin account just for you, then log in as that account, and then downgrade that admin account. And don't create an account called 'admin' - it's a account that hackers like to attack.

Second, change the password for your hosting account. And then change the password for any FTP accounts.  That should prevent the developer from making changes to the database - or destroying files.

Third, change the password on your WP database. This will require changing the password in the wp-config.php file, so change that to the new password after changing the database password.

Fourth, get a complete backup of your site (database and files). Your hosting account probably has a backup process you can use, or you can add a backup plugin to the site.

Fifth, if you think the developer had access to your domain registration account, change the password there aslo.

All of these items are a bit technical, but there are many googles/bings/ducks where you can get help. You can also get help from your hosting place through their support. Doing the above will secure your site from damage by the web guy.

**Added**  (too long for a comment)

If the hosting account belongs to you, then you have ultimate control. Get it back under your control by changing passwords, etc.

If hosting account belongs to them, then you are (IMHO) within your rights to backup database to your local system, set up a new hosting account that belongs to you, and move the database to a new WP installatiaon on your new hosting account. That will also require changing the nameservers of your domain to point to the new hosting account. (I assume that you own the domain name also.._

(To lurkers - it's OK to get help on a system or have someone develop it for you. But you should normally 'own' the hosting/domain name - it belongs to you.)

Comment: Hi Rick, I should have mentioned, they have access to the hosting account, as they created this. Do you know what I should do if they have access?

Comment: It looks like the UpdraftPlus plug-in sorts my problem out if I don't have access to the hosting?

Comment: See what I added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks Rick, much appreciated.

Comment: @BaT  - glad to help. 
BTW, it's 'polite' here to 'checkmark' an answer that is helpful and answered your question. Helps others that might discover your question.